# Automatic Height for Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart

I'm following the documentation correctly with Chart.js and my Bar Chart is appearing too big until I click inspect element, then the chart seems to resize and snap into the correct position.

[Quick Screencast of Issue](http://cl.ly/2a3V1U1o1L1E)

There's no inline styles on my canvas element, the following styles come into play *once* I go to Inspect Element. I'm not sure where or how the chart is getting those inline styles.

```
canvas{
 width: 100% !important;
 max-width: 800px;
 height: auto !important;}
```

Comment: maintainAspectRatio:false - try this

Comment: @crc442 Nope, still only snapping to the right size when I inspect element.

Comment: Can you paste some relevant part of the code?

Comment: I think the chart might be inited before the element is actually visible, you need to trigger a Resize event on the windows once visible or trigger a rerender of the chart..

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  data: {
    ...
  },
  options: {
    animation: {
      onComplete: function (animation) {
        this.options.animation.onComplete = null; // disable after the first render
        animation.chartInstance.resize()
      }
    }
  }
});
```

as an alternative, why do you set the `width` to 100% but not the `height`? In your screen vid it's inside of another `div` anyways so I'd try playing w/ the `height` too. Finally, I'd refrain from using the global `canvas` CSS selector -- rather use `canvas#barChart` because otherwise it'll be applied to all canvases, not just the `chartjs` ones.